# Help finding a fast permutation/combination algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, permutation, combinations

I've been using the algorithm found here at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Premutations.aspx) which has worked well provided I want the length of each permutation to be the same as the number of characters I used to generate the permutations (e.g. "code" would yield "code", "coed", "cdoe", etc)

What I want to do is expand on that to find an algorithm that would give me all the permutations/combinations regardless of length (e.g. "code" would yield "c", "co", "cod", "code", "coe", "coed", etc)

Am I using the correct terminology?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks